# How do I set default group ownership for files in a directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, lamp

I am running a cakephp webapp on Linode LAMP.  I am finding that my temp files are created with root:root ownership.  But the webapp is running with Apache's permissions (www-data). This causes warnings any time there is a new file created because it is not writable for user www-data.

How do I change the default ownership to www-data on any new files created in the temp folder?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 24):

To assign group ownership by www-data regardless of the uid/gid of the process that creates the file, you need to set the setgid bit on the directory.

```
    sudo chown :www-data <dir>
    sudo chmod g+s <dir>
```

Note that you must also make the directory writable by whatever process will create the files. If that's anyone but root, you may also need `chmod o+rwx` to get things working properly.

Comment: What about sub-directories?

Comment: Appending the -R flag to chown and chmod makes that command recursive. So the commands below will assign default group ownership to <dir> as well as all subdirectories of <dir>: `sudo chown -R :www-data <dir>` and `sudo chmod -R g+s <dir>`